# Algorithm to flatten peak usage over time?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an environment that serves many devices spread across 3 time zones by receiving and sending data during the wee hours of the night.  The distribution of these devices was determined pseudo-randomly based on an identification number and a simple calculation using a modulo operation.  The result of such a calculation creates an unnecessary artificial peak which consumes more resources than I'd like during certain hours of the night.

As part of our protocol I can instruct devices when to connect to our system on subsequent nights.

I am seeking an algorithm which can generally distribute the peak into a more level line (albeit generally higher at most times) or at least a shove in the right direction - meaning what sort of terminology should I spend my time reading about.  I have available to me identification numbers for devices, the current time, and the device's time zone as inputs for performing calculation.  I can also perform some up front analytical calculations to create pools from which to draw slots from, though I feel this approach may be less elegant than I am hoping for (though a learning algorithm may not be a bad thing...).

(Ultimately and somewhat less relevant I will be implementing this algorithm using C#.)

Comment: I don't find the explanation of the problem completely clear? What are we distributing? How can a (more or less) random distribution result in in a significant peak? What would happen if instead the distribution was simple round-robin?

Comment: The peak is artificially created due to time zones and the modulo operation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to avoid the spikes associated with using random times, look at the various hashing functions used for hashtables. Your reading might start at the wikipedia articles on the subject:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Basically, divide whatever you want your update window to be into the appropriate number of buckets. One option might be 3 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds = 10800 buckets. Then use that as your hashtable size, for the chosen hashing function. Your unique input might be device ID. Don't forget to use GMT for the chosen time. Your programming language of choice probably has a number of built in hashing functions, but the article should provide some links to get you started if you want to implement one from scratch.

This approach is superior to the earlier answer of random access times because it has much better evenness properties, and *ensures* that your access patterns will be approximately flat, as compared to the random function which is likely to sometimes exhibit spikes.

Here's some more specific information on how to implement various functions:

http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You say that you can tell devices what time to connect, so I don't see why you need anything random or modulused. When each device connects, pick a time tomorrow which currently doesn't have many devices assigned to it, and assign the device to that time. If the devices all take about the same amount of resources to service, then a trivial greedy algorithm will produce a completely smooth distribution - assign each device to whatever time is currently least congested. If the server handles other work than just these devices, then you'd want to start with its typical load profile, then add the device load to that. I wouldn't really call this "analytical calculations", just storing a histogram of expected load against time for the next 24 hours.

Or do you have the problem that the device might not obey instructions (for example it might be offline at its assigned time, and then connect whenever it's next on)? Obviously if your users in a particular time zone all start work at the same time in the morning, then that would be a problematic strategy.

Comment: The problem with this is it has a feedback loop component.  If on the first night it happens that 2am is the least busy, it will allocate resources to 2am.  That will make 2am the most busy if incidental traffic was randomly allocated that first night, so it will then schedule everything away from 2am, causing an inefficient use of the time around 2am.

Unless a stable distribution of incidental traffic is attainable, then uniform allocation across intervals will always be optimal.

Comment: If currently 1am is the most busy time (say, 1.5 million hits), and 2am the least busy (say, 0.5 million hits), then my suggestion is to instruct 0.5 million of the 1am-hitters to hit at 2am in future. I don't see how this has any feedback loop: just keep an array of buckets containing an integer, "how many hits are scheduled for this time tomorrow", and fill those buckets uniformly. There is no over-compensation, unless you use the faulty algorithm "how many hits are scheduled for this time tomorrow, *not including the ones I've already moved from other times*". So don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply take the number of devices and divide your time interval into n equal segments and allocate each segment to a device, informing them of when to connect when they next connect.

This will give you an optimally uniform distribution in all cases.

Normalize all times to GMT, what do you care about time zones or day light savings time or whatever?  Now is now no matter what time zone you're in.

Adding a random distribution can lead to clumping (a uniform random distribution is only uniform in the limit, but not necessarily for any particular sample), and really should be used if there's no feedback mechanism.  Since you can control to some extent when they connect a random component is not at all necessary and is not even remotely optimal.

If you're concerned about clock drift across devices consider even if you added randomness this wouldn't decrease the randomness of your clock drift in any way, and would only contribute to an even less optimal allocation.

If you want to ensure a stable distribution of devices by region, then compute the ratio of devices per region, and distribute the slot allocations appropriately.  For instance, if you have 50/25/25 by time zone respectively, assign slots to the first time zone, then the next two slots to the remaining time zones, then repeat.